# How to make a copy of form being submitted along with values in the controls

Tags: asp.net, caching, webforms

I have a ASP.net webform for users to fill. I don't want to just save the values of the controls, I want to save the whole form along with values entered or selected in the controls. So the result would be an .htm file along with users selections and inputs.

How can I do that?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this article can lead you to a solution.  It's about emailing and entire web control probably the same as an entire web form.

[Article to email entire web control](https://web.archive.org/web/20210510025209/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/091102-1.aspx)

On the other hand you could use JQuery along with Ajax to take the entire Html generated by ASP.NET and send it to the server.

Here's an example :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "YourURLToSaveWebForm",
    type: 'POST',
    data: { WebForm: $(document).html() },
    success: function (result) {
        alert('Completed...');
    },
    error: function (request, error) {
        alert(request.responseText + error);
    }
});
```